# Solve the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$9^x=5^x+2\sqrt{20^x}+4^x$$

I'm not really sure where to start. I tried simplifying with logarithms and factoring out the x but it ended up looking just as complicated..

Comment: x=2 works, and I do not think there is any other solution.

Comment: It's ok. I think the way to argue this is that the LHS grows faster, so there is no way that RHS can catch up with LHS again, for x>2.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I found that x=2 is the only solution but I don't know how to prove this

Answer (score 5):

$$
9^x=5^x+2\sqrt{20^x}+4^x=(\sqrt{5}^x+\sqrt{4}^x)^2\implies 3^x=\sqrt{5}^x+\sqrt{4}^x.
$$
Now consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=(\sqrt{5}/3)^x+(\sqrt{4}/3)^x$. You can verify that $f'<0$ everywhere so $f$ is strictly decreasing and, hence, injective.

[image: Plot of $f$]

Therefore, $x=2$ is the unique solution to $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Showing that there is a unique solution by the decreasing function makes sense to me. But can you show how you got the algebra down to $(\sqrt{5}^x+\sqrt{4}^x)^2$ Thanks again. You're help is really appreciated!!

Comment: @ OP: you can just expand using the formula $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

Comment: I think he's reffering to the other direction (without guessing).

Comment: Write the equation as $9^y = 5^y+4^y$ where $y = 2x$ makes it a little simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Were you asked to show your solutions?  If not, then by trial and error, $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
9^x=5^x+2\sqrt{20^x}+4^x\\
\Rightarrow (5+4)^x = 5^x + 2 \cdot 5^{x/2}\cdot 4^{x/2} + 4^x
$$

Compare this with $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

It is clear that $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
9^x&=5^x+2\sqrt{20^x}+4^x\\
9^x-5^x-4^x&=2\sqrt{20^x}\\
 \text{At this point, one solution jumps out}&\\
9^2-5^2-4^2\space 
=\space 81-25-16\space 
=\space 40&=2\sqrt{20^2}\\
\implies x=2
\end{align*}